# Print lines between patterns, excluding between patterns that doesn't match

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching

So I have an input such as this:

```
start 
abcd
sfd 
afsdaf
afsaf
end 1

start 
sdfo
efsf
end 0

start 
sdf
efsf
end 2
```

so I want to  only print lines between start and end (including start and end) but only when the second field of `end` line is larger than 0 (so between `start` and `end 1`, `start` and `end 2`; but not between `start` and `end 0`). Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$NF' file
start
abcd
sfd
afsdaf
afsaf
end 1

start
sdf
efsf
end 2
```

Since your records are separated by blank lines and they all start with "start" and end with "end" the fact that they start with "start" and end with "end" is irrelevant. All we need to consider is the final space-separated field in each blank-line separated paragraph being non-zero like above. Look for `If RS is null` in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html if you don't know what `RS=` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
/start/ { toprint=$0 ; save=1; next }
save { toprint = toprint "\n" $0 ; } 
/end/ {if (($2> 0) && save) { print toprint ;} save=0 }'
```

When you see a "start" line, start saving. If we are saving then append the data to the stuff we might print. When you see an "end" line, if we are saving and the second field is more than zero then print out what we have, and stop saving.

Comment: It could be better to use `toprint = toprint RT $0`, so any record separator becomes valid/usable.

Comment: @Isaac shouldn't it be `ORS`, then? (At least, I'm not familiar with `RT` in `awk` ...)

Comment: @AdminBee `RT` is the gawk-only variable that gets populated with whatever string the regexp stored in `RS` matched. In this case given `RS` has it's default value of `\n` the only functional difference between using the value of `RT` or `ORS` would be for the last record read IF the file didn't end in a newline (which it should) so using `ORS` is preferable to `RT` since it's portable to all awks and is also preferable to hard-coding the value that you assume `ORS` has - `"\n"`. So the code in question should be `toprint ORS $0` as you suggested.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you, I guess there is still a lot to learn for me ...

Comment: @AdminBee you're welcome. The good news is that the awk language is tiny so there really isn't that much to learn. Imagine trying to learn perl instead :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Gulp ;) ... although, it might be worth the challenge